# I have to compare only date but in table field created_at has both date time , how can ignore time in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have to compare only date not time but in db date time is available in created_at field. i have to ignore time i need only date from db to cmpare in where clause.

```
$this->db->select('o.* , c.email');
$this->db->from('order as o');
$this->db->join('customer as c', 'o.customer_id=c.id','left');
$this->db->where("CAST(o.created_at) BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2");
```

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') BETWEEN `2019/06/04` AND 2019/06/21' at line 4

```
SELECT `o`.*, `c`.`email` FROM `order` as `o` 
LEFT JOIN `customer` as `c` ON `o`.`customer_id`=`c`.`id` 
WHERE CAST(o.created_at) BETWEEN `2019/06/04` AND 2019/06/21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert them to `Y-m-d` format first by doing

```
$start = str_replace("/","-", $date1); // 2019-06-04
$end = str_replace("/","-", $date2); // 2019-06-21
```

and then for query side,

```
// you should cast as something but you left blank. Instead use as DATE
$this->db->where("CAST(o.created_at AS DATE) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");
```

Because `Y/m/d` does not default format MySQL or php use to match with `date` data type.

The syntax for CAST:

```
CAST( value AS type )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php side you need to use the MySQL date format for your `$date` variables (`YYYY-MM-DD`). And then, in your query, you need to specify the data type for the `CAST()` and quote your values:

```
$this->db->where("CAST(o.created_at AS DATE) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'");
```